Why are these two hotkeys only compatible in a certain order?
With the following example, I can fire both hotkeys just fine:
#if GetKeyState("space", "p") && WinActive("ahk_exe Everything64.exe")
<+f::
tooltip f and space
return

#if WinActive("ahk_exe Everything64.exe")
<+f::
tooltip f with no space
return

But if I reorder it like this, then I can only fire the first hotkey:
#if WinActive("ahk_exe Everything64.exe")
<+f::
tooltip f with no space
return

#if GetKeyState("space", "p") && WinActive("ahk_exe Everything64.exe")
<+f::
tooltip f and space
return

What gives though?

I have zero windows and autohotkey knowledge, but this looks like matches are tried in order, first wins. In your second snippet the second section's condition is strictly narrower than the first one's, thus it is never matched.
